# bitmap from byte arry of pixels in metro app(win 8)

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, dicom

I want to create a bitmap from a byte array of pixel in metro Apps. Earlier below function was used for the same:

```
//Here create the Bitmap to the know height, width and format
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap( 352, 288, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);  

  //Create a BitmapData and Lock all pixels to be written 
  BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                       new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),   
                       ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

  //Copy the data from the byte array into BitmapData.Scan0
  Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);


  //Unlock the pixels
  bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);


  //Return the bitmap 
  return bmp;
```

but BitmapData class is not present in windows 8 now. Please suggest any alternate way for the same.

thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not entirely mistaken, part of the code above is taken from the [Evil DICOM](http://evildicom.rexcardan.com/) library, from the `ImageHelper.GetBitmap` method.

I have myself made an attempt to port this code to *Metro* (or whatever Microsoft is going to call it eventually), and here is what the Metro analogue of `ImageHelper.GetBitmap` looks like in my port:

```
public static BitmapSource GetBitmap(float[] pixels, ImageProperties properties)
{
    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(properties.Rows, properties.Columns);

    using (var stream = bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
    {
        var bytes = new byte[4 * pixels.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            var greyness = properties.WindowAndLevel.GetValue(pixels[i]);
            bytes[4 * i] = greyness;
            bytes[4 * i + 1] = greyness;
            bytes[4 * i + 2] = greyness;
            bytes[4 * i + 3] = 0xff;
        }

        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

(Actually, I am using `stream.WriteAsync` in my own code, requiring the method to be declared as `async`. However, this is irrelevant for the above question as such.)

This answer is similar to Diogo's, but if you are not already "there" hopefully this answer can lead you more directly to your goal.

**UPDATE**

I have now published my Evil Dicom port to Metro on Github. You can find the repository [here](https://github.com/cureos/Evil-DICOM), and here is also a display from a very simple Metro application where I have used this Evil Dicom Metro port:

[image: Metro DICOM Viewer]

Comment: Hi Anders, I tried to use the lib and it worked perfectly. Can you pls tell me how we can get tags of DCM files from this lib.

Comment: The original author of Evil DICOM, Rex Cardan, is currently in the process of making a complete overhaul of the library. You can follow the "works in progress" [here](https://github.com/rexcardan/Evil-DICOM). As a result of this overhaul, the "old" web site is being retired, but you can still find some Getting started information for the old library (which also applies to my Metro adaptation) [here](http://evildicom.azurewebsites.net/getting-started-with-evil-dicom).

Comment: BTW, @Pankaj, if my answer answered your question, please do not forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23138).

Comment: I am getting crash in function of   public static float[] GetPixels(PixelData data, ImageProperties properties) of imagehelper class if I try to open two dcm image one after one. the line if (data.Format == FrameDataFormat.NATIVE) crashes saying data is null. some time it doesnot crashes but rarely happens like this.

Comment: Also when I add the line var dicomFile = new DICOMFile(file); in code , it is not working properly. Only this line works pic.Source = await new ImageMatrix(new IStorageFile[] { file }).GetImage(0); and this also only one time.

Comment: @Pankaj Please post these issues on the _cureos/Evil-DICOM_ [Issues site](https://github.com/cureos/Evil-DICOM/issues) instead. And do consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23138) my answer to the original question by clicking the V button at the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the WritableBitmap class.

Something like that should work:

```
WriteableBitmap newBmp = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
Stream stream = newBmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream();

stream.Seek(0, 0);
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
newBmp.Invalidate();
```

You'll probably have to use the following namespaces for that to work:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
```

Comment: Thanks!! but This I have already tried. It didn't worked. Here for detail, I would like to add that I have got this pixel array from parsing of dicom image.

Comment: Did it throw an exception, or the image was distorted? If it was the first, what kind of exception did happen? Also, which colospace are you using?

Comment: Hi Diogo, Actually after this I am trying to display this writablebitmap in image control but its displaying nothing. Also i tried to save this image and I wrote below code for the same. With this code I see a distorted image is saved in folder.

Comment: it showing nothing in image control but when i save file using below code, it save distorted image                   IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
              BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, writeStream);
              encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, StreamBuffer);
              await

Comment: The color are distorted, or the image size is distorted? In both cases, remember the bytearray uses the bgra colorspace. If you're processing it using rgba, just change the order. If the image is grayscale, I'm not sure how the WriteableBitmap class works, but maybe you'll have to copy the grayscale values twice and use a fixed value for the Alpha channel.

Comment: Thanks Diogo a lot. What do you mean by "copy the grayscale value twice" as my image is repeating same thing twice in view. Cann you please elaborate the things which need to be done here. I am simply traversing the byte array in this way.

Comment: ~for (i = 0; i < StreamBuffer.Length - 4; i = i + 4)
          {
var a1 = StreamBuffer[i + 3];
var r1 = StreamBuffer[i + 2];
Var g1 = StreamBuffer[i + 1];
 var b1 = StreamBuffer[i + 0];
  a = 0xff;
  r = (byte)((0.311 * r1) + (0.486 * g1) + (0.213 * b1));     
  StreamBuffer[i + 3] = (byte)a;
  StreamBuffer[i + 2] = (byte)(r > 255 ? 255 : (r < 0 ? 0 : r));
  StreamBuffer[i + 1] = (byte)(r > 255 ? 255 : (r < 0 ? 0 : r));
  StreamBuffer[i + 0] = (byte)(r > 255 ? 255 : (r < 0 ? 0 : r));
   }!

Comment: Ok, I see you're trying to convert the image to grayscale. I tested that code here, and it worked. Does the StreamBuffer lenght equal the image width * image height * 4?